# Windows 8.1 Facebook App Events

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm writing a Windows 8.1 universal App (WinRT).

I need to integrate with Facebook to track App Events.

I made the same thing in an Android App using the AppEventsLogger.

I added the "Facebook SDK for .NET" to my project using NuGet, but I cannot find any way to track the App Events (like activateApp, deactivateApp, logEvent)

Are these functionalities I need included in the SDK I'm using?
Can I track these events in any other way in a WinRT Application?

Thank you all.

Comment: Hi, have you find any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Any news on this problem?